# angular2 bind toClass syntax meaning

Tags: angular

Could anyone explain me what does

```
 bind(UserService).toClass(UserService)
```

mean in Angular2 ?

in ng-book

```
export var userServiceInjectables: Array<any> = [
  bind(UserService).toClass(UserService)
];
```

Comment: [`bind` is marked as deprecated](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/bind-function.html). I guess it is abandoned syntax for `... = [{ provide: UserService, useClass: UserService }]` or just `... = [UserService]`.

Comment: @estus If you post it as answer Whisher can accept it and the question is marked as answered.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Sure. Haven't even remembered about `bind` until this moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`bind`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/bind-function.html) is marked as deprecated‌​. It [was deprecated](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#api-deprecation) in favour of [`provide`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/provide-function.html), which is deprecated also.

Currently [the providers are defined as POJOs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dependency-injection.html#!#providers):

```
export var userServiceInjectables: Array<any> = [
  { provide: UserService, useClass: UserService }
];
```

Or just:

```
export var userServiceInjectables: Array<any> = [UserService];
```